# OneDrive for Business Encryption

Tags: encryption, onedrive

This article and video implies that OneDrive for Business is inherently encrypted, in what seems to be a fairly sophisticated way: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/data-encryption-in-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-online-6501b5ef-6bf7-43df-b60d-f65781847d6c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

I'm curious if that's the general view shared by users. I'm looking for a simple way to share encrypted data via the cloud, and since my clients have OneDrive for Business, that may be as simple as sharing a specific OneDrive for Business folder.

Comment: Microsoft holds all the keys. That’s really all one needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already encrypted by your PC you don't need to worry as much about your providers encryption.

I have little doubt a TLA or court can get the data, but if you are protecting against hackers, and you are not very sophisticated, very often using cloud offerings will provide a better level of "background security" by contracting it out to the experts that maintain these clouds- of-course it's still possible for the users PC to be compromised.